# How to toggle a panel in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I would like to have a single keybinding to toggle a panel (for example, the solution explorer) - in other words, when the panel is not visible, pressing the key would display it, and pressing the same key again would hide it. The keybindings menu offer only the following:

[image: solutionExplorer related keybindings]

Currently I'm using the `View.SolutionExplorer` to display it when it's hidden, but there's no option for the toggling behaviour I described above. VS2022 doesn't apparently support macros either. Any suggestions?